# JSP - Authentication

Tags: jsp, web.xml

i have this simple login.jsp file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">  
  <table border="0">
  <tr>
  <td>Username</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Password</td>
  <td><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <center>
  <input type="submit" value="Login!">
  </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is config for my web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>Security</display-name>
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>
           SecuredBookSite
        </web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/Success</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>       
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
</web-app>
```

But when i run this code, i get the following error message:

**HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page**

What must i do?

My tomcat-user.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="administrator" password="password" roles="admin"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Thanks for help

**EDIT**

Here's my servlet:

```
package security;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/Success")
public class Success extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(request.isUserInRole("admin"))
    {
        System.out.println("approved!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("NOT approved");
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: AFAIR, you can't directly link to the login.jsp page. Instead, you must link to a protected page. This will make the server display the login page if the user is not logged in yet, and after successful login, the user will be redirected to the requested protected page.

Comment: I don't understand. What must i change, to run the code? In the <form-login-page> tag i call the login page, if a user is not logged in yet.

Comment: You probably have a link to the login page. You must not do that. You should only link to actual pages of the app. If the actual page is protected, the container will display the login page. I can't tell you what to change precisely, since you didn't show the page that caused this error to happen, and didn't describe what you did to get this error.

Comment: Ok i have edit my share. Now u can see my servlet, which should called if a user is successfully logged in. The error page is showing correctly is the user password is wrong

Comment: That doesn't help at all. What did you do to get this error?

Comment: I've set the username in the login.jsp username-field  as "administrator" and in the password-field "password". After submit i get this error.But for example if i write in the  password field "pasword", then i see the error.jsp page, without the "HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page" error Message

Comment: And how did you come to the login page in the first page?

Comment: Now i have handle it. Thanks